# runtime error 1004 calling macros in another workbook that was opened via vba

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

The following code used to work, but now returns a Runtime Error 1004.

```
Sub ResizeListObject_DateRange()

    ' Do Some things ...

    Call HubLink.HubLaunch
        Application.Run "'" & MacroHub & "'!" & "ResizeListObject", TableName, LstRow
    Call HubLink.HubClose
End Sub
```

Below is the HubLaunch sub. It opens a second workbook that includes a macro that is then asked to run.

I can avoid the runtime error by commenting out the line "Call HubLink.HubLaunch" and instead manually open the MacroHub.xlsm file (via File > Open > [Choose My File]) before executing sub "ResizeListObject_DateRange".

In the immediate window I verified that ?Workbooks.Count = 2. I do not understand why my HubLaunch sub is opening the MacroHub.xlsm workbook in such a way that its Macros are inaccessible to the first workbook.

Can anyone explain the error?

Thanks.

```
    ' Opens the Workbook that stores all common macros
    Sub HubLaunch()

        ' The current workbook
        Dim WkBk As String
        WkBk = ActiveWorkbook.Name

        Dim WkBk_Hub As Workbook

        ' If not already launched, open the Common workbook that stores all common macros
        On Error Resume Next
        Set WkBk_Hub = Workbooks(MacroHub_Path & MacroHub_FName)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If WkBk_Hub Is Nothing Then
            Set WkBk_Hub = Workbooks.Open(MacroHub_Path & MacroHub_FName)
        End If

        ' Reselect the calling workbook
        Workbooks(WkBk).Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: are you sure all the variables you have are correct when passed into the arguments now? I see that you pass `MacroHub` as the variable for filename in `Sub ResizeListObject_DateRange` and `MacroHub_FName` in `Sub HubLaunch`.

Comment: Yes all code definitely runs correctly when I open the workbook via the file method instead of having vba open the workbook for me.

Comment: I have also tested by hardcoding the MacroHub path; fails unles I manually open the workbook

Comment: If run on its own does Hublink.HubLaunch successfully open the second workbook?

Comment: Yes it opens seemingly as intended. My problem is that the macros in each workbook don't seem to be able to communicate

Comment: Try adding `application.automationsecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow` before opening the other workbook.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. That did the trick. My IT department must have made some silent security changes